# How to get the value of "<select></select>" from a view into a Controller's "ActionResult"?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a  tag and a button. On click of the button, an actionResult in a controller is called. Like this.

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetAllItems", "Items")'">Get Items</button>
```

And here's the `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult GetAllItems() {
        string selectedItem = string.Empty;
        ItemsRepository itemsRepository = new ItemsRepository();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(itemsRepository.GetAllItems());
    }
```

**`selectedItem` is the variable I want to store either the selectedText or the selectedValue. But I don't know how to.**

This is the `<Select>` tag.

```
<select style="width:170px" id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>
```

And this is the *rough* function to get the different results from `onChange` event.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ItemsID").change(function () {
        var a = $('#ItemsID option:selected').val();
        var b = $('#ItemsID option:selected').text().trim();
        var c = $('#ItemsID option:selected').index();

        alert(a);
        alert(b);
        alert(c);
    })
});
```

Please help.

Comment: You can use AJAX bound for `change` event to pass selected value into controller action method's parameter. Did you already find out how to use AJAX call?

Comment: I don't want it bound on `onChange` event, I want to get it on `onClick` event of button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to get the value of your select in the action method. Note that you must pass the `name` attribute of your html select element to Request.

```
var selectedValue = Request["Items"];
```

Also, make sure the button that is clicked submits a form by using code like below.

The main point is that you can only use Request object to access a html element value in C# code, provided the html element and the submit button are within the same form. If you use a button that redirects the user rather than submits a form  then this will not work, so it must be a submit type button as in code below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", "ControllerName")) {

          <select style="width:170px" id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />

}
```

Comment: It returns the following error

`selectedValue Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.`

Comment: I have unchecked the `Optimize Code` check, let me try again.

Comment: Does the select element contain items or its empty?

Comment: Its not empty. Its being filled by another `ActionResult`.

Comment: Here is the code that populates `<select>` tag

`public ActionResult ItemList() { var items = Items.GetItems(); if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { return Json(new SelectList(items.ToArray(), "ItemCode", "ItemDescription"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); } return RedirectToAction("Index"); }`

Comment: And its visually filled too.  Like, I can see it populated.

Comment: Ok. You want the selected value in your action method. Right?

Comment: Because that's when the `ActionResult` in question is being called.

Comment: Make sure that before button click the select element has some item selected.

Comment: Obviously, that's what I am doing.

Comment: Let me check again.

Comment: Do you have any other html elements in your page with the name attribute set to `Items`? If only one html element has that name then you should be getting the selected value in your C# code using Request["Items"].

Comment: There is no other named element, let alone named 'Items'.

Comment: Then change your button to a submit button like this: `<input type="submit" value=-"Submit" id="btnSubmit" />` and make sure there is a form in your html markup of view. Add form using code like this: `@using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", "ControllerName"))
{
     
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />
}`

Comment: The select element must be within the form that I have mentioned in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

location.href doesn't sent a POST request. What you got to do is to place a form tag with your ActionResult to make a POST request.

```
<form action='yourAction'>
<select name='name'></select>
<button type="submit">Get Items</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this `ActionResult`? Looks like HTML to me for `View`.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("GetAllItems", "Items", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "thisForm"}))
{
     <select style="width:170px" id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>
 <button type="submit" >Get Items</button>
}

Comment: Thank you for your help.